# Displaying all roles from db into dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I want to show all roles from db into a dropdownlist.I have override the GetAllUser method of role provider in this way.

```
       public string[] GetAllRoles()
         {
        string[] roles = Session.Query<RoleManager>()
                       .Select(r => r.roleName)
                       .ToArray();
        return roles;
         }
```

I have called this method in Controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DisplayAllRoles()
    {
        string[] allRoles = ((CustomRoleProvider)Roles.Provider).GetAllRoles();
        if (allRoles != null)
        {
            //bind dropDownlist list in view with all roles ???

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "List of All roles");

        }
        else ModelState.AddModelError("","No role exists.");
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.AllRoles,new SelectList (Model.AllRoles))
```

Now my question is that how can i populate a dropdownlist from that string array of roles.Can you please write the sample code for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SelectListItems. Simply populate all your roles into the view model

```
 public class RoleViewModel
 {
     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }
 }

 public ActionResult DisplayAllRoles()
 {
        var roleModel = new RoleViewModel();

        //string[] allRoles = ((CustomRoleProvider)Roles.Provider).GetAllRoles(); 
        var allRoles = new[] { "role1", "role2" }; //hard coded roles for to demo the above method.

        if (allRoles != null)
        {
            //bind dropDownlist list in view with all roles ???
            roleModel.RolesList = allRoles.Select(x => new SelectListItem() {Text = x, Value = x});
        }
        else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "No role exists.");

        return View(roleModel);
 }
```

In your View

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RolesList,
                     new SelectList(
                         Model.RolesList, 
                         "Text", 
                         "Value"))
```

**Update to demo the selected Value :**

In RoleViewModel add an additional property to get the selected value

```
  public class RoleViewModel
  {
     public RoleViewModel()
     {}

     public string SelectedRole { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }
  }
```

In your Razor View, wraps the dropdown list with the Html.BeginForm and include a Submit button.
Also change the dropdown to have the Model.SelectedRole.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayAllRoles", "Home"))
 {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RolesList,
        new SelectList(
        Model.RolesList,
        "Text",
        "Value", Model.SelectedRole))


     <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
 }
```

In your Controller, creates a Post action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayAllRoles(FormCollection form) {
        var selectedValue = form["RolesList"];
        return View();
    }
```

The above selectedValue is the one that you selected.

Comment: I dont want to hard code role values.In my case string array allroles contains roles for which i want to populate a dropdownlist.

Comment: Of course. In your example, the hard coded values will be replaced with the real implementation string[] allRoles = ((CustomRoleProvider)Roles.Provider).GetAllRoles();                   That's why I commented out this line.

Comment: Scope of var  roleModel is within if statement but we are returing it outside if.How can make it accessible outside if.

Comment: @Wasfa - sorry I just updated the code so it is accessible outside if. Also I don't think you need ModelState.AddModelError("", "List of All roles"); Mainly because you don't want the model to be in an error state when all roles are returned.

Comment: Thanks Raj.I also want to access the Selected value of dropdownlist in http post method of controller.Will you please guide me how can i do that??

Comment: Sure I have updated my answer to guide you accessing the selected value.

Comment: var selectedValue is null in httpPost method and it is giving an error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Error line is @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RolesList,
        new SelectList(
        Model.RolesList,
        "Text",
        "Value", Model.SelectedRole))